# Google Maps, scale circle based on Zoom

Tags: jquery, google-maps, zooming

I have a Google map with circles being displayed, using a radius that scales down using the index of a data set (1, 2, 3, 4..):

```
 var radiusTest = 1 - (mapDataTrending[i].index) * .1;

 var populationOptions = {
  strokeColor: "#fdb913",
  strokeOpacity: 0.35,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  fillColor: "#fdb913",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapDataTrending[i].lat, mapDataTrending[i].lng),
  radius: radiusTest * 800
};

cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
```

I would like if the circles did not get larger as the user zooms in.  The circles are scaling as the user zooms, and i would like them to not get as large if the user is zoomed in to an integer like 20.

Here is how I am making my map:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.26826, -97.743044),
    zoom: 14,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Is there a way I can control the circle radius based on the maps Zoom?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a circle that stays the same size at different zoom levels, it may be best to go with [symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols).

As shown in this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined), they scale their size with zoom level by default. You also have the option of setting [properties](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#properties) that a normal circle has such as `fillColor` and `strokeOpacity`.

From the example I linked:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: map.getCenter(),
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 10
  },
  draggable: true,
  map: map
});
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Google Maps has a [`zoom_changed` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en), you can subscribe to this and call the `setRadius` method on your [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Circle). Of course you have to define the function `getCustomRadiusForZoom` yourself depending on how big the circles should be

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    cityCircle.setRadius(getCustomRadiusForZoom(zoomLevel));
  });
```